# Do Java EE interceptors take part in container managed transactions of an EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, interceptor

Somehow this piece of information seems to be missing in the usual Java EE documentatation resources:

Unless there is an external transaction active, the container starts a new transaction when calling a business method of an EJB with container managed transactions, if this business method is assigned a transaction attribute that requires a transaction (e.g. `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED`).

Now, if this method call is intercepted by a method interceptor

```java
@AroundInvoke
public Object onMethodCall(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception
{
  doSomethingBefore();
  ctx.proceed();
  doSomethingAfterwards();
}
```

Will the methods `doSomethingBefore()` and `doSomethingAfter()` be called within this new transaction context, or will the transaction be restricted to the call `ctx.proceed()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [@AroundIvoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/AroundInvoke.html):

> AroundInvoke method invocations occur within the same transaction and security context as the method on which they are interposing.